# PHP syntax error for storing data into mysql db

Tags: php, mysql

I have resolved the issue. The following code now works perfectly.
Thank you all.

Please the relevant section of dbcontroller.php file as follows:

```
<?php
class DBController {


function runQuery2($query) {
    $result = mysql_query($query);
            return $result;
    }

 }
```

In addition, I have amended my original MySQL statements in my main html/php file to look like this:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 require_once("dbcontroller.php");
 $db_handle = new DBController();


if(!empty($_POST["submit"])) {

  if ($db_handle->runQuery2("INSERT INTO cquestionstable 
  (postid, ccode,    nick, queries) VALUES ( 1,'cc-001', 'james', 'what    
   could be the problem?')") === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
     } else {
    echo "Error in posting question, pls try again." . "<br>";
   }

?>
```

Thanks n cheers.

Comment: what error you are getting? also change the line like this:- `echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $db_handle->error;` remove `**`

Comment: If postid is set as auto_increment, I would not include it in the `insert statement`. Maybe the problem is in the data you are trying to insert. `var_dump` the data.

Comment: Show us the dbHandler class.

Comment: to Ohgodwhy: pls find dbhandler class as asked.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once("dbcontroller.php");
    $db_handle = new DBController();

    if(!empty($_POST["submit"])) {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO cquestionstable (postid, ccode, nick, queries) VALUES ( 1,'cc-001', 'james', 'what could be the problem?')";
        if ($db_handle->runQuery($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $**sql . "<br>" . $db_handle->error;
        }
    }
?>
```

I see the errors already.

First `if (!empty($_POST["submit"])) {` should be `if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {`

Then you used `if ($db_handle->runQuery($sql) === TRUE) {` which should actually be `if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {`

Then in your echo you used `$**sql` which should be `$sql`

Then i did not know what dbcontroller.php was but the final code should be

```
<?php
    // session_start(); You do not need this when inserting into database
    include "dbcontroller.php";

    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO cquestionstable (postid, ccode, nick, queries) VALUES (1, 'cc-001', 'james', 'what could be the problem?')";
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $connn->error;
        }
    }
?>
```

`dbcontroller.php`

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

?>
```

If you still do not understand why it is not working please look at [w3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)

Hope this is the answer you we're looking for.